# Trying to access array offset on value of type null on php 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I inherited a Wordpress website built on an older version of php. I'm getting this error on php 7.4
`Trying to access array offset on value of type null in functions.php on line 846 - 849` The four lines are part of some custom code the developer created that I don't entirely understand, so I'm not sure how to fix it.  Research leads me to believe it's not checking if the array is empty. I've tried to do that but nothing works. Hoping someone can catch the problem.

Line 846 starts at `'Icon1'` and line 849 at `'Icon4'`

```
function add_icons( $post_id ) {
$MyArray_field = get_field( 'custom_icons', $post_id );
    $MyArray       = array(
        'Icon 1' => $MyArray_field['field_name_1'] ? '<span class="field1" title="Icon 1">1</span>' : '',
        'Icon 2' => $MyArray_field['field_name_2'] ? '<span class="field2" title="Icon 2">2/span>' : '',
        'Icon 3' => $MyArray_field['field_name_3'] ? '<span class="field3" title="Icon 3">3</span>' : '',
        'Icon 4' => $MyArray_field['field_name_4'] ? '<span class="field4" title="Icon 4">4</span>' : '',
    );
    $MyArray       = array_filter( $MyArray );

    return implode( ' ', $MyArray );
}
```

Comment: which line is 846?

Comment: You sure you meant v4. 7?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

Check for key exist or not using `isset()`

try this

```
function add_icons( $post_id ) {
$MyArray_field = get_field( 'custom_icons', $post_id );
    $MyArray       = array(
        'Icon 1' => isset($MyArray_field['field_name_1']) ? '<span class="field1" title="Icon 1">1</span>' : '',
        'Icon 2' => isset($MyArray_field['field_name_2']) ? '<span class="field2" title="Icon 2">2/span>' : '',
        'Icon 3' => isset($MyArray_field['field_name_3']) ? '<span class="field3" title="Icon 3">3</span>' : '',
        'Icon 4' => isset($MyArray_field['field_name_4']) ? '<span class="field4" title="Icon 4">4</span>' : '',
    );
    $MyArray       = array_filter( $MyArray );

    return implode( ' ', $MyArray );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The error has gone but the function isn't working properly. It is suppose to show 1-4 icons on a post, depending on what's selected in the post admin. However, is now showing all four icons on every post.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a few more developers, it was pointed out to me that it was not an error, but a "Notice:" I was getting on that function so I decided to hide it for now. Yes, it's a hack, but I can't afford to hire someone to fix small problems. If I start getting more problems from the php update, I will come up with a better solution.

Comment: In fact, this is not a real "answer" but a workaround, the original problem is unsolved.

Comment: Should I have put it in a comment instead?

Comment: Yes, that would be a possibility. Or edit your original post. The sense behind that is, that an "should" really show a definite solution for the problem, so that someone else with the same issue can solve it using the answer. ^^